# mcollective ping not working

Tags: puppet, mcollective

I am facing the below error while setting up mcollective activemq setup on centos, could you please let me know what went wrong in the setup?

```
mco ping

The ping application failed to run, use -v for full error details: 
Could not create instance of plugin MCollective::Connector::Activemq: undefined method    `str_to_bool' for MCollective::Util:Module
```

Ruby version:

```
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
```

client cfg file:

```
#topicprefix = /topic/mcollective
main_collective = mcollective
collectives = mcollective
libdir = /usr/libexec/mcollective
#logger_type = console
logfile = /etc/mcollective/mco.log
loglevel = debug

# Plugins
securityprovider = psk
plugin.psk = unset


connector = activemq
plugin.stomp.pool.size = 2
plugin.stomp.pool.1.host = localhost
plugin.stomp.pool.1.port = 61613
plugin.stomp.pool.1.user = mcollective
plugin.stomp.pool.1.password = marionette


# Facts
factsource = yaml
plugin.yaml = /etc/mcollective/facts.yaml
```

Regards,
Satya

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/651866/how-to-run-puppet-on-multiple-nodes-at-once-using-mcollective/652556#652556

Comment: What is the output of `mco ping -v`? Did you install ActiveMQ on your broker?