# How to run Puppet on multiple nodes at once using MCollective?

Tags: activemq, puppet-agent, mcollective

**Aim**

At the moment there are more than 100 systems in the office and the expectation is that the number will increase. All systems are managed by Puppet. If Puppet code changes on the Puppet Master and needs to be implemented on multiple systems, Puppet is run manually by executing `sudo puppet agent -t` on every system. Sometimes a change needs to be implemented on more than 10 systems. In order to safe time the idea is to use MCollective, i.e. run puppet one time on all systems instead of running puppet on every system.

---

**Attempt**

**ActiveMQ**, **MCollective Server** and **MCollective Client** have been installed on the **Puppetmaster**. Once `mco ping` is run the **Puppetmaster** can be found. After installing **MCollective Puppet Agent** and running `mco rpc puppet runonce` Puppet is run on the **Puppetmaster**.

In order to connect a *remote* **mcollective-client** the idea was that **activemq** and **mcollective-client** have to be installed and run in order to find the second host by issuing `mco ping`.

*/var/log/mcollective.log*

```
INFO -- : activemq.rb:114:in `on_connecting' TCP Connection attempt 23 to stomp://mcollective@stomp1:6163
```

*/etc/activemq/activemq.xml*

```
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
        </transportConnectors>
</broker>
```

*/etc/mcollective/server.cfg*

```
connector = activemq
plugin.activemq.pool.size = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.1.host = localhost
plugin.activemq.pool.1.port = 61613
plugin.activemq.pool.1.user = mcollective
plugin.activemq.pool.1.password = helloworld
```

One of the assumptions was that multiple hosts should be configured in the server.cfg. While trying to make it work it became unclear how the architecture should look like. **One** ActiveMQ, **one** MCollective Server and **multiple** MCollective Clients (one on every node) are required or not?

---

**Expected result**

The expected result is that `mco ping` finds the **Puppetmaster** and the **remote client**. Once this works it would be possible to run Puppet on both systems using MCollective. When it is possible to execute Puppet on these two systems using MCollective, multiple nodes will be added and Puppet will run on these systems once `mco rpc puppet runonce` has been executed.

---

**Current outcome**

As it is not possible to find the remote client by executing `mco ping` it is not possible to run Puppet on both systems using MCollective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**One** ActiveMQ server is required, MCollective needs be installed on every node and the `plugin.activemq.pool.1.host` snippet needs to contain the IP of the ActiveMQ server.

[image]

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ mco ping
test                                  time=225.70 ms
test2                                 time=488.51 ms


---- ping statistics ----
2 replies max: 488.51 min: 225.70 avg: 357.10
```

**/etc/mcollective/server.cfg**

```
connector = activemq
plugin.activemq.pool.size = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.1.host = IP_ACTIVEMQ_SERVER
plugin.activemq.pool.1.port = 61613
plugin.activemq.pool.1.user = mcollective
plugin.activemq.pool.1.password = helloworld
```

Once the Puppet nodes were found, executing `mco rpc puppet runonce` runs Puppet on all the systems.